# Given a macro, how to specify a pointer to a function that's a class member?

Tags: c++, callback, macros

I'm trying to wrap my head around this macro structure, but my C skills are nowhere near adequate. I have a macro structure that I have to work with, which sets up mouse regions, and function callbacks to call when region is hit. Everything works fine if the functions are global, but now I'd like to specify callback functions that are members of classes.

What I have is:

```
#define FCAPI   __stdcall

typedef struct  MOUSECALLBACK
{
    PIXPOINT    relative_point;
    PVOID       user_data;
    PMOUSERECT  mouse;
    PIXPOINT    screen_point;       // window client coordinates of the click
    PVOID       reserved;
} MOUSECALLBACK, *PMOUSECALLBACK, **PPMOUSECALLBACK;

// arg1 is actually pointer to MOUSECALLBACK, but for compatibility is defined here as a pointer to PIXPOINT
typedef BOOL FCAPI  MOUSE_FUNCTION(PPIXPOINT arg1, FLAGS32 mouse_flags);
typedef             MOUSE_FUNCTION      *PMOUSE_FUNCTION;

#define OBJHDR_FOR_MOUSE_CALLBACK(PIXPOINT) ((POBJHDR)(((PMOUSECALLBACK)(PIXPOINT))->user_data))

typedef struct  MOUSERECT
{
    MOUSE_RECT_TYPE rect_type;          // type of mouse rectangle (parent, child, eol)
    PIXBOX          relative_box;       // relative sense rectangle (relative to parameter to register function)
    CURSOR_TYPE     cursor;             // cursor to display when over this window
    ID              help_id;            // pop-up help id
    FLAGS           mouse_flags;        // types of mouse activities to look for
    ID              event_id;           // event to generate if mouse_flags is satisfied (implies simple mouse_flags)
    PMOUSE_FUNCTION mouse_function;     // function to call if mouse_flag is satisfied
} MOUSERECT;

#define MOUSE_PARENT_BEGIN( x, y, w, h, helpid )                        {MOUSE_RECT_PARENT, {x, y, w, h}, CURSOR_NONE, helpid, MOUSE_NONE, 0, NULL, NULL},

#define MOUSE_PARENT_END                                                {MOUSE_RECT_END_PARENT, {0, 0, 0, 0}, CURSOR_NONE, HELP_NONE, MOUSE_NONE, 0, NULL, NULL},

#define MOUSE_PARENT( x, y, w, h, helpid )                              MOUSE_PARENT_BEGIN( x, y, w, h, helpid )                    \
                                                                            MOUSE_PARENT_END

#define MOUSE_BEGIN( name, helpid, x, y )                               MOUSERECT   name[]  = {                                     \
                                                                            MOUSE_PARENT_BEGIN( x, y, 0, 0, helpid )

#define MOUSE_END                                                       MOUSE_PARENT_END                                            \
                                                                            {MOUSE_RECT_EOL, {0, 0, 0, 0}, CURSOR_NONE, HELP_NONE, MOUSE_NONE, 0, NULL, NULL}};

#define MOUSE_CHILD_EVENT( x, y, w, h, cursor, mouse_flags, event_id )  {MOUSE_RECT_CHILD, {x, y, w, h}, cursor, HELP_NONE, mouse_flags, event_id, NULL, NULL},
#define MOUSE_CHILD_FUNCT( x, y, w, h, cursor, mouse_flags, function )  {MOUSE_RECT_CHILD, {x, y, w, h}, cursor, HELP_NONE, mouse_flags, 0, function, NULL},
```

Then, I call macros to define mouse regions, and the pointers to functions (in this example, MFA_B_T1) to call when the region is hit:

````
MOUSE_BEGIN(MFA_mouse_rect, HELP_NONE, 0, 0)
MOUSE_CHILD_FUNCT(20, 20, 6, 6, CURSOR_HAND, MOUSE_LEFTSINGLE, MFA_B_T1)
```
MOUSE_END

BOOL FCAPI MFA_B_T1(PPIXPOINT relative_point, FLAGS32 mouse_flags)
{
    ```
        return FALSE;
}
````

Now, what I need is to make MFA_B_T1 a member of a class, say GDIPlus_Object. So, I need something like this:

```
MOUSE_CHILD_FUNCT(20, 20, 6, 6, CURSOR_HAND, MOUSE_LEFTSINGLE, GDIPlus_Object::MFA_B_T1)

BOOL FCAPI GDIPlus_Object::MFD_B_T1(PPIXPOINT relative_point, FLAGS32 mouse_flags)
{
    return true;
}
```

Except, I am not sure how to call a function member from the macro as set up above. I can't change macro structure, its usage is a project requirement.

Please help!

Comment: Looks like that API doesn't pass you any context into the callback, so that would not be possible to do without self modifying code. Look at `MOUSECALLBACK` however, it has a `user_data` field which could be used to store `this`. So try to figure out if there's a way to get an instance of `MOUSECALLBACK`.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what a macro is in C or C++ too - there is no such thing as a "macro structure". As to your question, a pointer to a member function (more correctly "non-static member function") is a completely different thing from a pointer to a function (like you would use in C) so can't be used the same way - in particular, it can't be called directly using syntax like `member_function()` outside another non-static member function. You clearly don't understand that distinction, so your question is meaningless - and any answer will be meaningless to you.  Voting to close accordingly.